# How to Install wordpress with SQL server

Tags: php, asp.net, sql-server, wordpress, plesk

I have a website created with asp.net mvc and SQL SERVER database, and im trying to create BLOG sub domain on my site with wordpress.
Is it possible installing wordpress on PLESK with my current SQL server database?

Comment: when you install wordpress ,wordpress create its own tables and Do your tables same with wordpress's tables structure?

Comment: @shaghayeghsheykholeslami Im trying to create tables in sql server, not mysql.

Comment: so I think you couldn't . you could use old database for your wordpress or maybe similar structure but you couldn't install your wordpress on different structure .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow below steps carefully or read [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/05/12/running-wordpress-on-sql-server/), it will help you to reach your quest.

**Step 1 – Enable the MySQL extension:** I know this seems counter-intuitive (aren’t we going to run WordPress on SQL Server?), but because of the way the SQL Server patch is architected (it is intercepting and re-writing MySQL queries), WordPress expects the MySQL extension to be enabled in your PHP installation. If you don’t enable the MySQL extension, you will see the following error later in the setup process:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension

**Step 2 - Download the WordPress on SQL Server Distribution:** https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami. Extract the files from the downloaded .zip file and copy the contents of the WordPress folder to a folder in your website’s root directory called wp-sqlsrv.

**Step 3 – Enable IIS detailed error messages:** Create a web.config file with the following content and put it in the wp-sqlsrv folder (more detail about why this step is necessary is available here):

```
<configuration> 
 <system.webServer> 
   <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/> 
 </system.webServer>
```

**Step 4 – Enable writes permission to the wp-sqlsrv directory:** In general, WordPress expects to have to write access to the wp-content folder (where plug-ins and themes exist) during set up and configuration. The sqlsrv patch takes advantage of this expectation by making a field_map.php file in that folder (at installation time) which maps the WordPress tables, column names, and types to their SQL Server equivalents.

**Step 5 – Browse to http://localhost/wp-sqlsrv/.** Select "Database Type" properly.

**Step 6 – Remove IIS Detailed Errors and Configure URL Rewrite:** Replace the content of the web.config file you created in Step 4 with this content:

```
<configuration>  
<system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
        <rules>  
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">  
                <match url="*"/>  
                <conditions>  
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>  
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>  
                </conditions>  
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>  
            </rule>  
        </rules>  
    </rewrite>
```

You are ready to start blogging.

Comment: Is visitmix.com  down?

Comment: I think so. sorry. you can use https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami to download WordPress. tell me if you have any problem in the next steps.

Comment: I have not used wordpress before, I think there is not a good solution for connect wordpress to sql server.maybe i have to make a blog system with asp.net. what is your opinion?

Comment: I think if you didn't move forward yet, it's not a bad idea to use ASP.NET projects like DotNetNuke instead of WordPress. I use WordPress a lot and I really enjoy it, but I'm sure there are too many good CMS that are compatible with MSSQL.